# ProcessCenter - NoTargetForURIException in http://localhost:9081/ProcessCenter

Tags: ibm-bpm

I've installed BPM 8.0, created profile and in fact, able to access WAS console via http://localhost:9061/ibm/console/login.do where I see these ports. But my ProcessCenter doens't seem to run on 9080/ 9081. Any suggestions please?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the full URL to go to process center? The default configuration doesn't handle bad URLs properly.  You should be going to https://localhost:9444/ProcessCenter  If you only go to the port it will throw a SRVE0255E error.

Comment: Yes, I am using the full URL like localhost:9081/ProcessCenter. I've tried your URL and got this error. "Error 404: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.exception.NoTargetForURIException: No target servlet configured for uri: /ProcessCenter". Does this mean that the server is unable to find the file/ class called 'ProcessCenter' ? Where does the webserver serve the file from ?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and tell us what you did to get your server up and running.  It feels like perhaps it hasn't been completely installed/configured.  What do you see when you go to the installed applications view?  On my 8.5.6 install there are 43 "apps" listed as installed.  Comments don't allow a screen shot, so I can't show them here.

Comment: When you created your profile, did you set the BPM hostname to localhost or some other hostname?  You will need to use the BPM hostname to access your Process Center console.